# Go tool pprof list command gives 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected'

Tags: go, profiler, pprof

I've got a cpu profile file that I've been examining for a bottleneck in my code and using the commands like top10 works fine. However, when I want to look at the source code listing by typing

```
list Remove
```

Where `Remove` is the function I want to list, it gives the following output:

```
(pprof) list Remove
Total: 207 samples
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of Go? and how are you generating the profile?

Comment: 1.6 and passing the --raw flag to go tool pprof localhost:6060/blah